# What could be causing Roblox Experiences to fail to start?

Tags: technical-issues, roblox

I have a problem where I cannot get Roblox Player to fully launch when trying to connect to an Experience (A game). After clicking the play button, the white box with the green progress bar and the Roblox logo pops up, but once it goes away, the Roblox process is basically killed (from what I see in the Task Manager). I can't figure out why this is happening. I've tried a lot of solutions suggested by the Roblox Support Team, myself, and other websites, but none of those solutions seem to work. I hope I do not need to wipe my system or re-install Windows  I think this problem may require an advanced solution.

System specs:

- GTX 1650 LP (4GB)
- i5-4590 3.3GHz
- 480gb Kingston SSD
- 500gb WD HDD
- 16gb RAM 1666MHz
- (forgot my PSU)

OS: Windows 10 Pro. Version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1202)

I currently do not have MSI Afterburner, nor the Rivatuner programs installed for my GPU which have interfered with other programs before.

If anyone needs more info like Logs or something, I'll gladly provide the information in a reply.

Comment: Are you using Windows10Universal.exe (the Roblox launcher from the Microsoft Store), or robloxplayerbeta.exe (downloaded from the website)?

Comment: @DisplayNameNotFound As Windows10Universal doesn't create a new window and simply updates the current window, it's definitely RobloxPlayerBeta.

Comment: @Corsaka Thanks!

Comment: @VM-431 Could you attempt a full reinstall of the Roblox app? I vaguely remember that working for me the previous time this didn't work. You might need to physically delete the `Roblox` folder in Program Files.

Comment: @Corsaka I am using the website version, not the one from the Microsoft store.

Comment: @Corsaka oh and I did try removing every trace of Roblox on my computer, still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can’t say for certain *why* this is happening, there may be a fix.

Delete robloxLauncher.exe, then try installing Roblox from the Microsoft Store.

Roblox from the Microsoft store also has better loading time.

*Note: the problem might not be your device, it might be that something is blocking roblox.com’s ability to open robloxLauncher.exe, (the application) but I’m just theorizing.*

Hope this helped.

Comment: This did help a bit. I have installed the Roblox from the Microsoft store, and that works just fine. I guess I'll have to use that instead of the web version. Thanks!

Comment: @VM-431 No problem! Good luck!

Comment: The web version of Roblox works now.. It was all because of the Nvidia GPU driver I was on. I updated it and it works now!

Comment: @VM-431 Ok, glad to know it works!